# Using CNAME results in website differences

Tags: heroku, responsive, cname

I've added a CNAME record to my domain, to redirect people to the heroku app that hosts a website.

Somehow, my website is responsive and mobile friendly when I go directly to the heroku page ([auspermaculture.herokuapp.com](http://auspermaculture.herokuapp.com)) BUT not responsive and mobile friendly at all when I go trough the domain name [www.auspermaculture.com](http://www.auspermaculture.com) (that redirects to the heroku app using a CNAME record)

I can only see the differences when I actually open up the websites on my phone (iphone 5). In my web browser, the website is responsive not matter what adress I browse to. So if you want to see what I'm talking about, you might have to use your phone.

Any idea what would cause the differences? And is there a way to solve it?

**UPDATE**
It's not a caching issue. 
After deleting all browser data on my phone, I still get these differences.
Here's 2 screenshots to clarify:

[image: auspermaculture.com]

[image: auspermaculture.herokuapp.com]

Comment: Isn't it just a caching issue? From Windows 10 Mobile both look the same. Screenshots might be useful to demonstrate what exactly you mean.

Comment: It's not a caching issue, I just deleted all my browser data on my phone and still have the issue. (Unless I need to do more to remove the cache...)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that Godaddy wrapped the whole website in a `<frameset>` because I forwarded the adress with masking. Forwarding it without masking turns out to be the solution.